# Derivation of superluminality in astronomy

Tags: astronomy, relativity

Can somebody provide derivation of the relativistic explanation of (apparent) superluminality in astronomy? The derivation on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superluminal_motion#Derivation_of_the_relativistic_explanation) seems to be a bit confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

You are at 'O' the object is moving from A,B and is further from you at A than it is at B (ie O-A is longer than O-B)

Imagine it flared when it was at A, the light from that would be on it's way to you along A-O, meanwhile the object moves to B and flares again.

That light left later but has a short distance to go to you. Imagine for example the two light beams arrived at O a day apart.

If you measure their angular separation between the two flares, and you estimate the distance when it is at 'B' you calculate that it has moved a distance C-B in one day -  which might appear to be faster than light.